# Redirect and Restore STDERR in Dancer

Tags: perl, stdout, stderr, io-redirection, dancer

When starting my `http server` I don't want to see `>> Dancer2 v0.201000 server <pid> listening on http://0.0.0.0:<port>` printed on the `stderr`. Thats why I added the following line before calling `start()`

```
get "/pwd" => sub {
    my $pwd = cwd;
    print STDERR "\n\n[PWD] : $pwd\n"; # this line is not being printed
    print "\n\n[STDOUT::PWD] : $pwd\n";
    my %responseHash = ( pwd => $pwd );
    my $response = encode_json \%responseHash;
    return $response;
};    

my $dancerStartErr;

sub startServer {
    open (local *STDERR, ">", \$dancerStartErr) 
        or die "Dup err to variable error: $!\n";

    start();
}

startServer();
```

The problem is that later I can't print something on the `STERR`. How can I reopen `STDERR` (`open(STDERR, ">", \*STDERR);` doesn't help)?

Comment: Do you want to disable all logging, or just the very first message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want your application to log anything, you can change the logging engine to use [Dancer2::Logger::Null](https://v1.metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Dancer2/lib/Dancer2/Logger/Null.pm). You do that by editing your *config.yml*, or in one of your environments. For example, to turn it off in producion, change *# appdir/environments/production.yml*.

```
logger: 'null'
```

The default is the logging engine `'console'`, which prints stuff to your terminal.

There are other Dancer2::Logger:: classes available [bundled with Dancer2](https://metacpan.org/release/Dancer2) and on CPAN [in their own distributions](https://metacpan.org/search?q=Dancer2%3A%3ALogger%3A%3A&search_type=modules). A better solution to just dumping everything into a black hole might be to log to a file instead. Documentation of how to configure it further can be found in [Dancer2::Core::Role::Logger](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer2::Core::Role::Logger).

Also note that instead of printing to `STDERR` in your code, you should use the logging keywords with the appropriate log level.

```
print STDERR "\n\n[PWD] : $pwd\n"; # this line is not being printed
```

This is not a good idea, because you cannot distinguish if this is an error, or a warning, or just debugging output. That's why there are different log levels built into Dancer2.

- `core`
- `debug`
- `info`
- `warning`
- `error`

All of them are available as keywords. There is documentation on it in [Dancer2::Manual](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Dancer2/lib/Dancer2/Manual.pod#LOGGING).

Since the working directory is probably not relevant in production, but only during development, you'd go with `debug`.

```
debug "[PWD] : $pwd";
```

That's it. It takes care of newlines and such for you automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [select](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/select.html) before redirecting to save it in a variable

```
my $oldfh = select(STDERR);
```

and then use it later

```
select($oldfh);
```

Also check out:

- [Capture::Tiny::Extended](https://metacpan.org/pod/Capture::Tiny::Extended)
- [How to redirect and restore STDOUT/STDERR](https://perltricks.com/article/45/2013/10/27/How-to-redirect-and-restore-STDOUT/)

Comment: I added a global variable `$STDERR_COPY` and then tried to print to stderr with `my $stdErr = select($STDERR_COPY);` and then I try to print on the `stderr` I get `Can't use string ("main::STDERR") as a symbol ref while "strict refs" `